# Issue on saving data into DB using play / Ebean

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean, playframework-2.3

I have 3 classes.

1. Car
2. User
3. UserCars

This 3 classes represents tables into my DB. The UserCars table links the Car and Users table and it's constructed the following way:

---Users---
int id
int cars_id
int user_id
-----

I try to save a car related to it's user by using the Users_car table.

These are my 3 classes: 
**Car**

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id; 
    public String brand; 
    public String model; 
    public String fuel;
    public double avg_cons; // Average consumption
    public double c02_cons;  
    public double htva_price; 
    public double leasing_price; 

    public static Finder<String, Car> find = new Finder<String, Car>(
            String.class, Car.class
    ); 

}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;  
    public String name; 
    public String username; 
    public String email; 
    public String password; 
    public String phoneNumber; 
    public Timestamp inscriptionDate;
    @Transient
    public Timeline timeline;

    public User(){}
}
```

**UserCars**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_cars")
public class UserCars extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id; 
    @ManyToOne
    public int user_id;  
    @OneToOne
    public int car_id; 

    public UserCars(int userId, int carId){
        this.user_id = userId; 
        this.car_id = carId;
    }

    public static Finder<String, UserCars> find = new Finder<String, UserCars>(
            String.class, UserCars.class
    );
}
```

And here is the way I saved it :

```
public static Result saveCar(){
        // Retrieve the current username
        DynamicForm params = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
        String username = params.get("username");
        User current = User.find.where().like("username", username).findUnique(); 
        int currentUserId = current.getId(); 

        // Get data from android and save it to DB
        Car car = Form.form(Car.class).bindFromRequest().get(); 
        int currentCarId = car.id; 
        UserCars userCars = new UserCars(currentUserId, currentCarId); 

        try {
            Ebean.save(car);
            Ebean.save(userCars); 
        } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return internalServerError("Car registration failed"); 
        }

        return ok(); 
    }
```

The thing is, at line `int currentCarId = car.id;`, th id is *always* 0. 
**Indeed** the id is only incremented when I save the car (`Ebean.save(car);`).

How can I increment the ID, so that this one is incremented correctly in order to create a correct instance of UsersCars?

Many thanks !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve means guess the id of Car before saving and pass to UserCars.Can you explain more?

Comment: @singhakash Yes, this is my question. But is that even possible? I already tried to use a static int into Car, but it does not work and it is not elegant at all... So yes, I need the Id of Car which is generated only when I call Ebean.save(). (Because only this method increment the id)

Comment: As per my knowledge `not possible`.Btw an specific reason for not using direct relation between Cars and User?

Comment: @singhakash No particular reasons, I find this way more convenient and elegant. Is there any workaround possible? Or bypass this issue?

Comment: Sorry but I disagree.I think at the end you are making ManyToMany relation between Cars and User.In your case you are explictly creating mapped table UserCars why to write this much code of creating UserCars etc rather then using ManyToMany annotation which will do everytning for you.

Comment: I don't get it. Should I delete the table UsersCars and just add a field @ManyToMany in User field on Car class?

Comment: yes I mean that but only if you dont want any extra field in third table apart from id,user_id,car_id.

Comment: @singhakash Can you please write an answer to explain me how I should perform it? Sorry, but it is kinf of unclear to me and see the whole code will probably help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create ManyToMany relation between Cars and User .Like

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model{

//other fields

@ManyToMany
public List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();

}

@Entity
public class User extends Model{

 //other fields    

@ManyToMany
public List<Car> users=new ArrayList<Car>();

}
```

The above code will automatically create a third table say User_Cars(you can change the name) having respective id of Car and User.

Also check [Example](https://github.com/cosmolev/BridgeTable/blob/master/app/models/Order.java)

Comment: okkk. For example, I frist create a user, and then if I want to add a car to this user, should I do an update?